# mod_deflate to compromise my site?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code example to compromise my website with deflate:

```
 <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
 </ifModule>
```

but I read on my provider site that I have also to insert this rule:
 1-**mod_gzip_on Yes ?**is this rule is must or do I have to ignoer it?the code above is sufficient.

my second question is: I read this advise below !!

**Some popular browsers cannot handle compression of all content so you may want to set the gzip-only-text/html note to 1 to only allow html files to be compresse. If you set this to anything but 1 it will be ignored.**

what I understand that some browsers they don't support compromise, should I insert also the rules below here:

```
**BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
 BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/ht**ml
```

or just ignore it?

Comment: What do you mean by "compromise?" That usually means to exploit a security vulnerability. Do you mean compression?

Comment: See BazzaDP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your first question but if it's about using mod_deflate over mod_gzip then the answer is to use mod_deflate. Development stopped on mod_gzip years ago and mod_deflate is part of standard Apache and also (despite its name) uses gzip - though can also use the less widely supported deflate option if you want to but that is not recommended.

As to your second question that is no longer necessary either. Some very, very, very old browsers had bugs in them for gzip but now all browsers handle it well and tell Apache if they don't. None of those older browsers are in use anymore and even if they were they probably couldn't open your site for other reasons. See here for gzip browser support: http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm

Comment: thnaks, so only this code below wil be enough to compress my website: <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
 </ifModule>
johannes

Comment: <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
 </ifModule>

Comment: Yes should be enough. Try it and see.

Comment: thnaks, it worked but now I ad another rule for cashing and I get internal error. this is the code:

Comment: Thanks it works but when I ad cashing rules I get internal error my website is gone:<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 weeks"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header unset ETag FileETag None
 Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule> what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I can't read that. Add to original question or open a new question for this.

Comment: thanks , I opened already new question  about the code I paste in my question that compression code is working but browsercashing code is not working  from the default Apache code. johannes